# Get the method output parameters parameters

Tags: java, reflection

I using the following code to get the method input parameter but I getting the wrong params
for example I for set salary I want to get the type (double )and the name (salary) .
what i miss here ?

```
public void setSalery(double salery) {
    this.salery = salery;
  }
```

this is the code

```
for (Method method : classHandle.getMethods()) {


            Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();

            for (Class<?> class1 : parameterTypes) {

                Field[] declaredFields = class1.getDeclaredFields();
                for (Field field : declaredFields) {
                    System.out.println(field.getName());


            }
```

Comment: You're currently printing out the *fields* of the parameter types. I can't immediately find any method which will give you the parameter names...

Comment: Well, what you are asking for, I faced this few months ago. But I couldn't find any way to get the names of the parameters. Probably because they are not stored as a part of the compiled class file. I thought there might be some way, like annotating the class in some way to tell it to store the names, but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the parameter *types* but not the parameter *names*. They are of no significance except within the method, which at this point is opaque to you.  `getDeclaredFields()` returns the fields in the *types*, not the parameter names.

To invoke such a method (using your example), assume

```
MyBean b = new MyBean(); // contains method setSalary(double salary)
Method m = ...           // a reference to a Method object for MyBean#setSalary(double salary)
double newSalary = ...;
```

Then do

```
m.invoke(b, new Double(newSalary));
```

Comment: Actually I want at the end to find all the Set methods and to send them parameter ,there is no way to do it ? my secnario is to get method name by string and to find all the sets method and than to send them the respective data..

Comment: For that you do not need the parameter name, only its type. When you invoke the method (using `Method#invoke(Object, Object...)`) parameters are matched by position, not by name.

Comment: Can  you provide some example please?